# SQL: Repair With Keycache

Tags: mysql

Now my MySQL server running a `REPAIR TABLE`, table is almost 15gb size. Status - `Repair with keycache`. How I can restart `REPAIR TABLE` with normal (`repair with sort`) mode?

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA thanks for your help, I just waited, and it's done in 10 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [**myisam_max_sort_file_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_myisam_max_sort_file_size) is probably too small.

Perhaps your [**tmpdir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) hasn't got the elbow room.

First, kill the repair right now.

Add these two lines to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 80G
tmpdir=/var/lib/mysql (or some other path or mount point)
```

Restart mysql and do the `REPAIR TABLE` again.

Give it a Try !!!